# OAuth "401: Invalid Credentials" after some period of time

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have created simple app using **Google Drive API** with **OAuth2 authentication** based on this sample [plus-appengine-sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/plus-appengine-sample/?repo=samples&r=71141ab7524177adeb4484035b6ecd23b18ac070#plus-appengine-sample%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fapi%2Fservices%2Fsamples%2Fplus)

So, I have two servlets implementations: `AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet` and `AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet` which should do all the hard work for me (oauth work flow).

```
public class DriveServlet extends AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet {
    private static final String MY_APP_NAME = "Drive API demo";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        AuthorizationCodeFlow authFlow = initializeFlow();
        Credential credential = authFlow.loadCredential(getUserId(req));

        if (credential == null) {
            resp.sendRedirect(authFlow.newAuthorizationUrl()
                    .setRedirectUri(OAuthUtils.getRedirectUri(req)).build());
            return;
        }

        Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(OAuthUtils.HTTP_TRANSPORT_REQUEST, 
                OAuthUtils.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(MY_APP_NAME).build();

        // API calls (examines drive structure)
        DriveMiner miner = new DriveMiner(drive);
        req.setAttribute("miner", miner);

        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/Drive.jsp");
        view.forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws ServletException, IOException {
        return OAuthUtils.initializeFlow();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
        return OAuthUtils.getRedirectUri(req);
    }
}

public class OAuthCallbackServlet extends AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws ServletException, IOException {
        return OAuthUtils.initializeFlow();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
        return OAuthUtils.getRedirectUri(req);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSuccess(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, 
            Credential credential) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.sendRedirect(OAuthUtils.MAIN_SERVLET_PATH);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, 
            AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl errorResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String nickname = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser().getNickname();
        resp.getWriter().print(
                "<h3>I am sorry" + nickname+ ", an internal server error occured. Try it later.</h1>");
        resp.setStatus(500);
        resp.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        return;
    }
}

public class OAuthUtils {
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE_PATH = "/client_secrets.json"; 
    static final JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    static final UrlFetchTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT_REQUEST = new UrlFetchTransport();
    private static final Set<String> PERMISSION_SCOPES = Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY);
    private static final AppEngineDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY = AppEngineDataStoreFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String AUTH_CALLBACK_SERVLET_PATH = "/oauth2callback";
    static final String MAIN_SERVLET_PATH = "/drive";

    private static GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = null;

    private OAuthUtils() {}

    private static GoogleClientSecrets getClientSecrets() throws IOException {
        if (clientSecrets == null) {
            InputStream jsonStream = OAuthUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE_PATH);
            InputStreamReader  jsonReader = new InputStreamReader(jsonStream);
            clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, jsonReader);
        }
        return clientSecrets;
    }

    static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws IOException {
        return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT_REQUEST,
                JSON_FACTORY, getClientSecrets(), PERMISSION_SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline").build(); 
    }

    static String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) {
        GenericUrl requestUrl = new GenericUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
        requestUrl.setRawPath(AUTH_CALLBACK_SERVLET_PATH);
        return requestUrl.build();
    }
}
```

Authentication flow works as expected as well as Drive API calls, but somehow, after some period of time, I'm getting this exception on refresh:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401
        {
        "code" : 401,
        "errors" : [{ "domain" : "global", 
                      "location" : "Authorization", 
                      "locationType" : "header", 
                      "message" : "Invalid Credentials", 
                      "reason" : "authError" }],
        "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
        }
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
        at sk.ennova.teamscom.drive.DriveMiner.getRootFolderId(DriveMiner.java:46)
        at org.apache.jsp.Drive_jsp._jspService(Drive_jsp.java:61)
```

It seems that token has **expired**, but isn't it a work for servlets to request a new access token with the refresh token which they stored? I use **offline** access type, so **refresh token** should be delivered to callback servlet at first request.

Here ["401 Unauthorized" when trying to watch changes on Google Drive with Java API Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173832/401-unauthorized-when-trying-to-watch-changes-on-google-drive-with-java-api-cl) are some hints where could be the problem, but handling token expiration should not be my case if I'm using these servlets (correct me if I am wrong). Also scope `DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY` seems OK for reading "drive" tree structure (get files of given folder and so on). Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first specify that you need a refresh token for offline / long term access and then save the refresh token for later use when the access token expires. You can request a new access token using the refresh token until the user revokes your access to her account. See the official documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh

Comment: I have access type offline in `OAuthUtils#initializeFlow()`. I've tried to call `credential.refreshToken()`, but it's still not working. I made some info prints - if I come back to my app, lets say after 2 hours, it will show old token with negative expiration. After page refresh it will show new expiration even without explicit call `credential.refreshToken()`, so servlets made token exchange automatically on background. But why after explicit page refresh?

Comment: Are you not saving the token received during the first page load in a persistent storage and getting a new token each time the servlet is invoked?

Comment: No, I don't have to store tokens explicitly. `AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet`, which is a superclass of `DriveServlet`, stores them. According to it's javadoc, I just need to call `loadCredential` to get persistent credential with tokens. Anyway, **I wrongly assumed that used abstract servlets automatically refreshes access token when necessecary** (they only do auth flow and stores the result - tokens). Calling `credential.refreshToken()`, **as you recommended**, is the way to do that. The reason why it didn't work the first time was, that I was testing wrong app version :).