# YouTube Android SDK - Invalid Credentials

Tags: android, google-api, youtube-data-api

I am receiving the `Invalid Credentials` error as a result to the following unit test:

```
List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
scopes.add(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY);
try {
    GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, scopes);
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(account.name);

    YouTube.Builder builder = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("TestApp");
    YouTube youtube = builder.build();

    YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youtube.channels().list("contentDetails");
    channelRequest.setMine(true);
    ChannelListResponse channelResult = channelRequest.execute();

    List<Channel> channelsList = channelResult.getItems();

    for(Channel channel : channelsList) {
        // Do things
    }
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), RESULT_REQUEST_AUTH);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When using this code, I firstly get the `UserRecoverableAuthIOException`, as expected. Once authorization has been given, I get the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

I have the following added to my Google API Console:

- Client ID for Android application
- Client ID for web application
- Key for browser applications

I also use the Google Drive SDK, which functions perfectly.

Under my list of APIs, I have:

- Drive API
- Drive SDK
- Google+ API
- YouTube Data API v3

Comment: take a look at this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11641277/3326331)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment I put on a bonus, I noticed that the App in question was linked to a co-workers Google account also. The correct signature for "Client ID for Android application" was on that account. Although, I had the correct signature also on the main account under keys.

Resolved now though.