# YouTube API returning 401 Unauthorized worked before

Tags: android, gradle, youtube-api

My full error:

> "Exception com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized"

Here is my Gradle code sample :

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret).build();
            credential.setAccessToken(videoDetails.accessToken);
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(
                    "My_Videos").build();

            System.out.println(":::uploadind videos on youtube");
            Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();
            setSnippets(videoDetails, videoObjectDefiningMetadata)
            InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT, new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/Desktop/uploadedVideos/146354902123990438f03164744e5a43f635081ba48dc.mp4")));
            YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);
            MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();
            uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
            Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
            res.put("Id", returnedVideo.getId())
            res.put("Tittle",returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTitle())
            res.put("isSuccess", true)
            println res
```

This code was working from six months but now it giving me exception .Please help.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331018/execute-youtube-playlists-got-googlejsonresponseexception-401-unauthorized it might help you.

Comment: i have read the documentation in which i have found that we must create a channel first for uploading the videos ? is their is any such thing then how can i do from my code? this is the link : https://developers.google.com/youtube/create-channel#Channel_Creation_Flow